# Disable a route based on model attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

Considering that I have a `Project` model, a project must be approved to be editable, a project with `status=pending` cannot be edited.

I used to do this by hiding edit links on the view based on the status attributes, but that doesn't stop the user from entering the route via the browser(e.g.: `projects/1/edit`), how can I make the edit route inaccessible within a given project status?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to make a conditional route. Have the controller check for status and only allow the update if `status =='pending'`.

```
def edit
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  if @project.status == 'pending'
    render :head, :status=>401
  else
    #your edit code
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add below before_action, based on which you can prevent project from getting edited.

```
#projects_controller.rb 
before_action :can_edit?, only: :edit

def edit 
  #your existing implementation goes here. 
end 

 def can_edit?
    @project =  Project.where(id: params[:id]).first

    if @project.status == pending 
     flash[alert] = "Sorry can't be edited"
     redirect_to projects_path
    end
 end
```